# How can I format a timestamp in Perl?

Tags: perl, time, format, timestamp, clock

I would like to get this timestamps formatting:

```
01/13/2010 20:42:03 - -
```

Where it's always 2 digits for the number except for the year, where it's 4 digits. And it's based on a 24-hour clock.

How can I do this in Perl? I prefer native functions.

Comment: While I understand your preference for native/core modules, DateTime and a few related formatters are absolutely worth the effort to get into your kit. http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POSIX) provides [`strftime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POSIX#strftime):

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -we 'print POSIX::strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S\n", localtime)'
01/27/2010 14:02:34
```

You might be tempted to write something like:

```
my ($sec, $min, $hr, $day, $mon, $year) = localtime;
printf("%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", 
       $day, $mon + 1, 1900 + $year, $hr, $min, $sec);
```

as a means of avoiding [POSIX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POSIX). Don't! AFAIK, `POSIX.pm` has been in the core since 1996 or 1997.

Comment: Judging from the unambiguous `01/13/2010` in the question, Brian seems to want a format of `"%m/%d/...` or even `"%D %T"`.

Comment: @gbacon `%D %T` did not work on `perl` 5.10.1 on Windows (it did on Linux), I decided to play safe. Thanks for noticing that I accidentally swapped `%m` and `%d`.

Comment: But don't avoid learning about `localtime` (or `sprintf`) either.

Comment: While using POSIX is cool and The Right Thing, I read somewhere that the module is quite resource-hungry.  So I guess you might want to sacrifice it in some cases...

Comment: @AloisMahdal Date::Format (as suggested by Diego Dias) also provides `strftime`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Date::Format](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TimeDate/lib/Date/Format.pm) formatting subroutines from CPAN.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subroutine that I use. It allows you to get the date time stamp in whichever format you prefer.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

sub getTime 
{
    my $format = $_[0] || '%Y%m%d %I:%M:%S %p'; #default format: 20160801 10:48:03 AM
    my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) = localtime(time);
    return strftime($format, $sec, $min, $hour, $wday, $mon, $year, $mday);
}

# Usage examples
print getTime()."\n";                    #20160801 10:48:03 AM
print getTime('%I:%M:%S %p')."\n";       #10:48:03 AM
print getTime('%A, %B %d, %Y')."\n";     #Monday, August 01, 2016
print getTime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')."\n";   #20160801 10:48:03
```